# is there a problem with my code? (python 3.72)

Tags: python

#The code is supposed to check if the user name typed in a text file. The text file includes

## Username

## John

## The text file is (Pdata)

```
f = open("Pdata.txt")
liner = f.readlines()
user = str(liner[1])
print(liner[1])
tf = True
while tf:
          print("hello")
          userr = str(input("Pls enter username"))
          if userr is user:
                    
                    tf = False
tf = False
```

Comment: Does it do what you want it to do?

Comment: use `==` not `is` operation

Comment: BTW, `input` returns a string, so there's no need to call `str` on the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

change the `while` like this:

```
while tf == True:
    print("hello")
    userr = str(input("Pls enter username"))
    if userr == user:
        tf = False
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used 'is' operator in your if statement.
What 'is' checks is if the two values are the same **object**, not if they have the same **value**.
Since 'userr' is not the same object as 'user' it returns **False**, so the loop never ends.

Instead I would suggest using `==` operator as it check the **values**:

```
if userr == user:
    tf = False
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `userr is user` this implies that you are checking whether they are the same object which is not and hence the comparison fails. What you need is the `==` operator.

Also, you need to strip the `\n` character after reading the name.

```
f = open("Pdata.txt")
liner = f.readlines()
user = str(liner[1].rstrip())                                                                                           tf = True
while tf:
      print("hello", user)
      userr = str(input("Pls enter username"))
      if userr == user:
          tf = False
tf = False
```